# ASP NET MCV performance(handling of threads) in multiple calls to asynchronous methods within a method

Tags: asynchronous, async-await

> if I have an asynchronous method that within the calls are made to other asynchronous methods with await, I have doubts first in the following:
>   1. when calling a method with await the thread return to the pool for later when the method finished executing uses the same thread or takes another from the pool, if there is another call to a method with await the process >is repeated?
>   2. If asynchronous methods are called within the method that these in turn call other asynchronous methods, how do you handle the thread for the request?

```
//1.First stage
public async Task<actionresult> Index
{
var result_1 = await Method1Async(x,y,z);
var result_2 = await Method2Async(x,y,z);
return View();
}
//2. Second stage
public async Task<actionresult> Index
{
//the thread is suspended and released.
var result_1 = await Method1Async(x,y,z);
return View();
}
private async Task<Int> Method1Async(int x,int y,int z)
{
//What happens with the thread?
return await Method1ImplemtationAsync(x,y,z);
}
public async Task<Int> Method1ImplemtationAsync(int x,int y, int z)
{
//What happens with the thread?
//call wcf for example :
return  await  sv.getCliensAsync(x,y,z);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`await` yields to its *caller*. It does this by returning an incomplete task.

If the caller method also uses `await`, then it yields to its caller, and so on. Eventually, when your action method yields to ASP.NET, then ASP.NET returns the thread to the thread pool.

For more information, see my [`async` intro](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and [`async` on ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx).

So, to walk through your example:

1. ASP.NET grabs a thread pool thread and invokes `Index`.
2. `Index` calls `Method1Async`.
3. `Method1Async` calls `Method1ImplementationAsync`.
4. `Method1ImplementationAsync` makes the remote call and `await`s the result. This causes `Method1ImplementationAsync` to return an incomplete task.
5. `Method1Async` `await`s the task returned from `Method1ImplementationAsync`. This causes `Method1Async` to return an incomplete task.
6. `Index` `await`s the task returned from `Method1Async`. This causes `Index` to return an incomplete task.
7. ASP.NET gets the incomplete task and returns the thread to the thread pool.

Later, when `getCliensAsync` completes:

1. ASP.NET grabs a thread pool thread and resumes executing `Method1ImplementationAsync`. It returns a value, which completes the task returned from `Method1ImplementationAsync`.
2. `Method1Async` then resumes executing. It returns a value, which completes the task returned from `Method1Async`.
3. `Index` then resumes executing. It calls `Method2Async`, ...

Comment: thanks, 
when var result_1 = await Method1Async (x, y, z); returns the complete task and asp, net obtains a thread from the pool to continue with the request and then invokes: var result_2 = await Method2Async (x, y, z); Is the process of the first asynchronous call repeated? I mean if await re-suspends the thread and then take another one of the pool thread when Method2Async returns the whole task.

Comment: @developer: The threads are not suspended. Instead, each `async` method is broken into pieces (with the "breaks" at the `await` points). So the method resumes executing, not the thread.

Comment: 1/2 @StephenCleary what you mention I am clear maybe you do not raise my question well, from the example public async
var result_1 = await Method1Async (x, y, z);
var result_2 = await Method2Async (x, y, z);
after the Method1Async method returns the complete task based on its explanation:

Comment: 2/2 6. Index awaits the task returned from Method1Async. This causes Index to return an incomplete task.
7. ASP.NET gets the incomplete task and returns the thread to the thread pool. then ASP.NET grabs to thread pool thread and resumes executing Method1ImplementationAsync. It returns to value, which completes the task returned from Method1ImplementationAsync.then when the method Method2Async asp .net is invoked I already take a thread group of threads. my question is is the same process of the Method1Async execution repeated?

Comment: @developer: Technically, when the returned task is completed, the `async` infrastructure will queue the continuation of the caller method to the thread pool. What *actually* happens is that there's optimizations in place to just keep the same thread pool thread and have it execute the caller method continuation directly. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: no, my question is if I have several asynchronous calls to the margin if a thread is reused or not the steps described in its explanation are repeated for each call to an asynchronous method? var result_1 = await Method1Async (x, y, z);
var result_2 = await Method2Async (x, y, z); What is described in your answer is repeated for both invocations?

Comment: @developer: If you call a method multiple times, then each invocation keeps track of its own state.

Comment: I was referring to different methods like the example methods, where you explained that when the call to the wcf service is completed asp .net takes a thread from the thread pool and resumes the request and when the Method2Async method is called my question is if it repeats the process mentioned above. I'm sorry because questions that may seem obvious to you but I do not wish to have a wrong knowledge about the subject.

Comment: @developer: Yes, the steps are the same for every asynchronous call. It may help to think about `await MethodAsync()` as being the same thing as `var task = MethodAsync(); await task;`. In other words, every method (including asynchronous methods) are invoked synchronously; it's only when that *task* is awaited where things can get asynchronous.